# Overall brief information about simd image processing solutions

Tags: nginx, simd-library

I whould like to be clear with three (or more) image processing libraries and approaches:

- C++ [Simd](https://github.com/ermig1979/Simd) library
- Python [Pillow-Simd](https://github.com/uploadcare/pillow-simd) library
- nginx [image filter](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_image_filter_module.html) solution uses [libgd](http://libgd.org/) library

Does Pillow-Simd uses Simd or uses a different C++ implementation and which one?

Does ngnix filter uses simd instruction set?

Is any nginx custom filter based on mentioned simd library or something like that?

If nginx image filter will support simd later, answer will be very appreciated.

Is any wrapper in any other lanuages like nodejs or go and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be I answer too late but...

1. Pillow-Simd uses its [own](https://github.com/uploadcare/pillow-simd/tree/simd/6.0.x/src/libImaging) SIMD implementation of image
   processing algorithm.
2. ngnix filter does not use any simd instruction
   set.
3. Custom ngnix filter can use any simd instruction set. Of course
   it is better to check avalability of this instruction set at
   runtime.
4. I still haven't any good news for you.
5. I know about [this](https://github.com/minio/go-cv) project.